# g++ accepts const as constexpr in static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11

When compiling the following code with `g++ 4.8.2` and `-std=c++11` flag it compiles with no errors:

```
    constexpr double C = 299792.458;
    const double local_max = 3.5;
    static_assert(local_max < C, "can't go that fast");
```

When compiling the following code it gives error:

```
    constexpr double C = 299792.458;
    double x = 3.5;
    const double local_max = x;
    static_assert(local_max < C, "can't go that fast");
```

Error message:

> a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> a.cc:6:2: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
>   static_assert(local_max < C, "can't go that fast");
>
> a.cc:6:2: error: the value of ‘local_max’ is not usable in a constant
>   expression
>
> a.cc:5:15: note: ‘local_max’ was not declared ‘constexpr’   const
>   double local_max = x;

My question is why it does not give error in the first case.

Does it depend on whether a `const` variable is initialized with a `constexpr` or not?

Comment: x get it's value at runtime, while static_assert is a compile time assert. You can't make a static_assert based on x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entirely correct, after

```
const double local_max = 3.5;
```

`local_max` is still not supposed to be a compile-time constant. This is a compiler bug, fixed in GCC 5.1. You can verify this on [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MYewdgzgLgpgHgBwE4AIAmICuAjANjFAYRQF4UAmATkoHZLyA6AFgFYAOAbgChRIp0seArhDAAhrgD6AWzFxSKAMwMW3aGKgBLYJLEQIMJFAAUI8VNnyAPEQA0KAETiwAcn4BzECigALDSgAzPSgHAEpuIA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g510%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%20-pedantic%22%7D%5D%7D), where you will see GCC's error messages, including:

> error: the value of 'local_max' is not usable in a constant expression

and

> note: 'local_max' was not declared 'constexpr'

Comment: Why can't it be a compile time constant? Then why does `const int i = 0; int x[i]` compile?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The rules for integer types are special. What the OP guessed (effectively implicitly `constexpr` if initialised with a constant expression) does apply for integer types, in order to let most valid C++03 code also be valid C++11 code.

Answer (score -1):

The first version is working because the local_max won't be in the memory. Whenever you use local_max, it will be replaced with it's value, which is known at compile time. So you can call a static_assert based on it.

However, in the second version local_max get it's value based on x, which is getting it's value at runtime.

You can't make a static_assert based on a variable which is getting it's value at runtime, because static_assert is a compile time assert.